# When I register it says the login message but the data isn't going to the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I took a look at this posted question: [I am getting no errors but the data is not going into the database on wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445015/i-am-getting-no-errors-but-the-data-is-not-going-into-the-database-on-wamp) but I did use mysqli for my code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  include( "includes/header.php" );
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  $register = $_POST['register'];
  //declaring variables needed for the registration form to prevent errors
  $fname = "";
  $lname = "";
  $uname = "";
  $email = "";
  $email2 = "";
  $password = "";
  $password2 = "";
  $signup_date = "";
  $username_check = ""; // check if username exists
  //assigning variables from the registration form
  $fname = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
  $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
  $uname = strip_tags($_POST['uname']);
  $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
  $email2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
  $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['password2']);
  $signup_date = date("Y-m-d");

  if ($register) {
    if ($email == $email2) {
      $username_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
      $row = mysqli_num_rows($username_check);
      if ($row == 0) {
        if ($fname&&$lname&&$uname&&$email&&$email2&&$password&&$password2) {
          if ($password == $password2) {
            if (strlen($uname)>25||strlen($fname)>25||strlen($lname)>25) {
              echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/ last name is 25 characters!";
            } elseif (strlen($password)>30||strlen($password)<5) {
                echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
            } else {
              $password = password_hash($password);
              $password2 = password_hash($password2);
              $query = mysqli_query('INSERT INTO users VALUES ("","$uname","$fname","$lname","$email","$password","$signup_date","0")');
              die("<h2>Welcome to HackerBits</h2>Login to your account to get started . . . ");
            }
          } else {
            echo "Your passwords don't match!";
          }
        } else {
          echo "Please fill in all of the fields.";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Username already taken . . . ";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Your emails don't match!";
    }
  }
?>
```

I know it is messy, I am new to php, only 1 week in. So like I said it goes to the `die("<h2>Welcome to HackerBits</h2>Login to your account to get started . . . ");` part of the code with no errors. Then when I go to my database the user is not in the table. Which means I can then go back to the registration form and put in the same values.

Sorry if this is a bad question, new to stakeoverflow, just tell me and I will fix it up :) I can also give you more info if needed. I am using MAMP by the way.

I connect to the database with the included script:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'taken-out');
?>
```

Errors given:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 27
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 28
>
> Warning: password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 37
>
> Warning: password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 38
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 39

They are all warnings which I don't think are fatal because it still executes the code to display the login message.

I have tried these lines:

```
$username_check = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
```

but same warnings.

Comment: `$username_check = mysqli_query('SELECT` you never connected. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Where is the connection parameter for `mysqli_query`?

Comment: I connected to the database though through the included script at the top

Comment: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) expects two parameters

Comment: word of advice, since you're hashing that password, you should NOT be manipulating it in any way. If a user enters valid characters that `strip_tags()` will "strip" away, they'll think that `<b>mypassword` is what they entered (and being a valid password, I might add) and it will fail upon trying to logging in. Do what you want, but you're going to get a reality check later on.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: *"I connect to the database with the included script:

<?php
  try {
      $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'Anim8ors');
  } catch (PDOException $error) {
      echo "Error!: " . $error->getMessage() . "<br/>";
      die();
  }"* - that's even worse. You're mixing MySQLi_ and PDO APIs.

Comment: I said I was new sorry, I changed that by the way and just did:   `  $db = new mysqli('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'Anim8ors');`

Comment: *"I took a look at this posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445015/i-am-getting-no-errors-but-the-data-is-not-going-into-the-database-on-wamp but I did use mysqli for my code."* which is one I answered btw and is a working solution.

Comment: [*Refer back to comment #1 then...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973802/when-i-register-it-says-the-login-message-but-the-data-isnt-going-to-the-databa#comment61503160_36973802)

Comment: well I am still having an issue still and would like some further insight

Comment: `'root', 'Anim8ors':`  I hope this isn't your real root password...

Comment: ...you have been given enough information, there isn't anything I can say or do here.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***, post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have fixed this line to what you have said in the other one now: `$username_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");`

Comment: you've my answer below @DarceyMckelvey and I didn't include what I already said in comments.

Comment: You accepted my answer and now decided to accept the other. amidst all the help I've given you. wow. ok, whatever.

Comment: Actually I think you should accept @Fred-ii-'s answer, it's more comprehensive

Comment: @luweiqi don't worry about it. but thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're welcome :-)

Comment: Fred-ii- I didn't refresh when I accepted the answer so I did realize you posted an answer and to be honest it was a group effort :) I'm sorry :( EDIT: changed it on @luweiqi request

Comment: It's ok Darcey. TBH, I didn't see @luweiqi 's answer when I was typing mine up as I was busy typing it all up and retrieving reference links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you're using here:

```
$db = new mysqli('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'taken-out');
```

That isn't the syntax to connect with here using the MySQLi_ API, that is PDO syntax.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Those are two different animals altogether.

Read the manual

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Example taken from it:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

So, replace `$mysqli` with the variable you're using in your query, and pass the db connection to that `mysqli_query()` function, as I said from the get go.

This besides all the other comments I left in your question and won't retype nor paste, so go over them all again.

Plus, make sure all your POST arrays contain values. Your HTML form is unknown.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Yet, do read the following Q&A on Stack in regards to what I said about password manipulation:

- [Cleansing User Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628418/cleansing-user-passwords)

And this one in Code review:

- [Login with password_hash()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash)

Comment: thankyou, fred-ii-  I have sorted out all the issues. @luweiqi helped lots. I will be sure to upvote both you guys when I can :)

Answer (score 2):

The connection parameter is required for [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
```

---

Your DB connection is for PDO:

```
$db = new mysqli('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'taken-out');
```

You need to use `mysqli_connect()`:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "taken-out", "users_table");
```

---

Also, you need to prevent SQL Injection using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lname']);
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['uname']);
```

Comment: still geting the warnings when I do: mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'"); Is it because I do not have access to $db? I included the file though?

Comment: @DarceyMckelvey Can you post the file you included?

Comment: I did its just the database connection. `<?php
    $db = new mysqli('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_table', 'root', 'taken-out');
?>`

Comment: and then included by: include( "includes/header.php" );

Comment: @DarceyMckelvey You are mixing PDO with MySQLi

Comment: I am also now getting new warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/social_network/index.php on line 16

Comment: fixed it :) Now just have to fix the warning: mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: as the OP stated; it was a group effort lol - I've no problem with whichever answer he wishes to accept. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

Well, mysqli needs to receive the connection handler as first parameter for query:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
```

And the password_hash needs a second parameter with the algoritm:

```
password_hash($password2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Use default algoritm
```

I recommend to use prepared statements in your queries, it's have more security.

Comment: still geting the warnings when I do: `mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'"); ` Is it because I do not have access to $db? I included the file though? Thanks for the password_hash fix :)

Comment: Your conection command is used for PDO connection, for mysqli the syntax is (in this case, you are using procedural methods):

$db = mysqli_connect('your_db_host', 'your_user', 'your_password', 'datbase_name');

OR you can use OOP method:
$db = new mysqli('your_db_host', 'your_user', 'your_password', 'datbase_name');

$query = $db->query('SELECT ... ');